# LWC recordType name and description Selection component

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, lwc-dom

I'm passing Map of record type - name and description from Apex to LWC and need to show the Name and description on UI with radio button to select name value.

JS Part

```
export default class xyz extends LightningElement {

    @track availableRecordTypes = [];
    @track retrievedTypes;
    @track recordLableSelected; 


    @wire(fetchRecordType)
    wiredRecordsMethod(result) {
        //debugger;
        //this.tableLoadingState = true;
        this.refreshTable = result;
        console.log(result.data);
        if (result.data) {
            var returning = [];
            var recordTypes = result.data;
            console.log('recordTypes -> ' + JSON.stringify(recordTypes));
            for(var key in recordTypes){
                //alert("Record Type Name: " + recordTypes[key]);
                returning.push({value:recordTypes[key],
                                name:key});
            }
            console.log('returning -> ' + JSON.stringify(returning));
            this.availableRecordTypes = returning;
            this.retrievedTypes = true;
        }
        else{
            alert("Temporary Error: There is a problem getting the Record Types.");// Temporary, Will be changed to ToastError.
        }
    }    
}
```

HTML part

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
        <table>
                <tr><td>
                    <legend class="slds-form-element__legend slds-form-element__label"><b>Select a Record Type</b></legend></td>
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                        <template for:each ={availableRecordTypes}  for:item="key">
                            <span class="slds-radio" id ={key.name}>
                                <input id={key.value} value={key.name} name="options" type="radio" onchange={optionSelected}/>
                                <label class="slds-radio__label" for={key.value}>
                                    <span class="slds-radio_faux"></span>
                                    <span class="slds-form-element__label"><b>{key.name}</b></span><br></br>
                                    <div class="slds-p-left_xx-large">
                                    <span class="slds-form-element__label"><b>{key.value}</b></span><br></br>
                                    </div>
                                    </label>
                            </span> 
                        </template>
                    </div>
                </tr>
            </table>                  
    </div>
</template>
```

Please suggest changes in HTML and JS file I want to show radio button- record Type and than description.

Comment: Why not use the [lightning-radio-group](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-radio-group/example) component?

Comment: Hi Sander, thanks for suggestion but I want to show value through iterator

Comment: Why does using the standard component prevent you from "showing the value through the iterator"?